# Solr search not indexing

Tags: solr

I am trying to get Solr to work with Magento EE. So far I have SOLR / Jetty running, Magento connecting to SOLR and Solr outputting logs when something is searched / indexed.

The problem I have is the following error:

> SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=397|1] Error
>   adding field 'attr_nav_multi_styles'='[, , , ]'   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:324)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:158)
>     at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:79)    at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
>     at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1372)    at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)

This looks to be related to layered navigation in someway (although 'use with catalog navigation' is disabled in the config.)

Does anyone have any insight into this? Specifically what this is referring to: attr_nav_multi_styles

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an attribute named styles?

Comment: Yes, I do. I have realised that any attribute that Solr is trying to index is prefixed with attr_nav_multi_ the problem doesn't seem to be limited to that attribute though. If I make that one not searchable then it will hit another, then another and so on all through any attributes.